# CSS counter-increment doesnt work with repeated table header

Tags: html, css, reactjs, printing, reactstrap

Im trying to make a report with page numbers. My table is too large and splits in many pages.

I need the page number to show in all theads. The thead repeats in every page and its just what i need, but counter-increment doesnt work and shows always "1".

Im using Reactstrap.

This is my code:

```
<div
    id="printMe"
>
    <Table size="sm" bordered>
        <thead>
            <tr style={{ borderTop: "solid" }}>
                <th colSpan="2">Companys Name</th>
                <th colSpan="1"><div className="pageNumber">Sheet </div></th>
            </tr>
            <tr style={{ borderBottom: "solid" }}>
                <th colSpan="2">Status</th>
                <th colSpan="1">Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data.map(est =>
                <tr>
                    <td>{est.code}</td>
                    <td>{est.name}</td>
                    <td>{est.details}</td>
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </Table>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
@media print{ 
  @page {
    margin: ${marginTop} ${marginRight} ${marginBottom} ${marginLeft} 
  !important;
  } 
  body{
    counter-reset: section;
  } 
  .pageNumber {
    counter-increment: section; 
  } 
  .pageNumber::after{
    content:counter(section);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have same issue here